# Avoid Table initialize to create table in Squeryl/Activerecord

Tags: scala, activerecord, playframework-2.0, squeryl

I have a database schema defined in mySQL already and I want to work on the play-2 with ActiveRecord application on top of it.

However, when I start up the project, it gives me error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user' already exists
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'user' already exists
and it is triggered by 
 org.squeryl.Schema.create(Schema.scala:181)
 models.Tables$.initialize(Tables.scala:7)
```

This is how it looks in my Tables.scala

```
object Tables extends ActiveRecordTables with PlaySupport {
    val users = table[User]
}
```

and my User.scala is:

```
case class User( 
    override val id: Long,  
    @Length(max=50) login: String
) extends ActiveRecord {
    lazy val role = belongsTo[Role]
}
object User extends ActiveRecordCompanion[User]
```

I tried to skip this in my global.scala

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
    //Tables.initialize
}
```

However, it still give me the same error

Is that anyway I can bypass the create table part?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a `user` table in your database with a different schema?

Since you are using the `PlaySupport` trait, I am guessing you are using the Scala ActiveRecord Play2.1 Plugin. As noted in the wiki of that project, add the following settings in conf/play.plugins

```
9999:com.github.aselab.activerecord.ActiveRecordPlugin
```

The `ActiveRecordPlugin` class initializes the tables on startup. So you shouldn't have to do that from your `Global onStart`

Comment: I check out the source code of activerecord plugin and see the onstart and onclose for initialization and cleanup.
The schema in database is a bit different from the one I declare in User.scala: I have a enum in the user table which ActiveRecord is not supporting so I have a case class instead.  Also, I have an password field that I indeed put in object:
extends ActiveRecord {

  @Transient @Length(max = 50)
  var password: Option[String] = _
  
  lazy val role = belongsTo[Role]
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use something like `MyDatabaseLibrary.create()` yourself ?

Check it out. You may try to search the directory for occurences of `.create`

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the issue by commenting out some of the table schema in Tables.scala.
I have multiple tables declared in Table object and one of them is not existed in the database, for example:

```
object Tables extends ActiveRecordTables with PlaySupport {
  val users = Table[User]
  val role = Table[Role]
  val group = Table[Group] //not exist which cause the error!
}
```

If one of the table is not exist in the database, the framework will create **ALL** tables in the order that listed in the object.
I did try to arrange the non-existing record to the top and the framework would create the table and failed to run.  However, if a situation as listed above, it would give error: table 'user' is already declared and **NO** table would be created in database.

Would raise as a bug to Activerecord and see if there's a solution.

Comment: this is a really annoying behaviour - I copied the report and opened an issue at https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord/issues/72